# Can't import TensorFlow in Anaconda

Tags: import, tensorflow

I've installed TensorFlow successfully with Anaconda command prompt, but when I use Ipython or use anaconda(spyder) to import Python, I get this error:

```
<ipython-input-2-41389fad42b5> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

When I check `pip list` in the list I can't find TensorFlow.
During the installation I've added this

```
C:> conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5 anaconda
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you followed all the step:

1. conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
2. activate tensorflow
3. pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

[image: select tesnorflow from drop-down]

When opening spyder from Anaconda please select environment as 'tensorflow'. There is one option as 'Applications On' just above the IDE's list. Select 'tensorflow' this should work. you can change your Environment variable(path) to

"XXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow"

Comment: I've changed the Environment variable(path) but it's not working.
 I don't understand this :
"There is one option as 'Applications On' just above the IDE's list. Select 'TensorFlow' this should work "